# 'in" word in title - Should it be written with a capital letter?

Tags: capitalization, titles

I'm developing an iOS app. At one of my screen the titles should be:
"4 videos in total" (intentionally lowercased).

What would be the right way to write it:

1. 4 **Videos In** Total
2. 4 **Videos in** Total
3. 4 **videos in** total

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: “The right way” according to whom? It’s your app, you decide how to capitalise your titles.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In terms of English Title capitalisation. Like you don't put "at" with "At"

Comment: There are no fixed rules. Do it how you think best.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, why not **total**?

Comment: @marcellothearcane oh, you mean why didn't I place "total" in **bold**? The word **videos** was already in lowercase, and too many words emboldened looks excessive. As long as the issue is clearly transmitted, why go overboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an argument for supporting each stylistic choice,

1. Capitalize every word for the sake of uniformity. This was more commonly the case in 19th-century book titles
2. Prepositions in titles are often lower-cased. This tends to be the more popular option nowadays
3. A heading is not the same as a title. The number of videos saved is not a title of an app, an article, story, song, or a book. That number will either increase or decrease according to each user. Only the first word (Four/4) needs to be capitalized

> **Books/films/songs/games** etc
>   Capitalise the first word of the title, and all words within the title except articles (a/an/the), prepositions (to/on/for etc) and conjunctions
>   (but/and/or etc).
>
> - The Last Mohican
> - Far from the Madding Crowd
>
> **Headlines, journal articles, chapter titles and lecture titles**
>   Only capitalise the first word, any proper nouns and the first word following a full stop/question mark/exclamation mark
>
> - ‘Who speaks for climate? Making sense of media reporting on climate
>     change’
> - Rock rafts could be ‘cradle of life’
>
> *[University of Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf)*

But in the end, this is not an issue concerning the English language per se but one of *style*, the app's author is perfectly free to select whichever style they prefer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with option 2 as it's more common now days, as you said. :)

Comment: Yes, I answered an "easy" and opinion-based question! I feel so good :)

Answer (score 1):

Mari-Lou's answer covers the reasoning.  For your specific application, the second option you give conforms to the majority of style guides of this is to be considered as a 'title'.